# How to check installed android sdk cmd

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

When I build my `Android` projects, I got this errors:

```
Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1.
Could not find com.android.support:design:23.2.1.
```

I compile it in `Ubuntu`, I have also isntall the support lib using the cmd:

```
 android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-support"
```

Results:

```
  Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1
  Installing Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1
    Installed Android Support Library, revision 23.2.193%)
  Done. 1 package installed.
```

How do I check if I have installed the lib? What is the possible reason.